# Prove that $||u+v||^2 -||u-v||^2 = 4(u\cdot v)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Prove that $\|u+v\|^2 -\|u-v\|^2 = 4(u\cdot v)$
where u and v are vectors in R^n

Edit: The subtraction part basically the second half, previously the math was incorrect.

My answer: Write u = ($u_1...u_n$) and v = ($v_1...v_n$)

$\|u +v\|^2 - \|u-v\|^2= (u_1+v_1)^2+...+(u_n+v_n)^2-(u_1-v_1)^2+...(u_n-v_n)^2
=u_1^2+2u_1v_1+v_1^2+...+u_n^2+2u_nv_n+v_n^2-u_1^2-2u_1v_1+v_1^2+u_n^2-2u_nv_n+v_n^2$

How do I get the above to become $4u_1+4v_1+...+4u_n+4v_n$?

Comment: You made an algebra mistake. Set $n=2$ so the algebra is simpler and try doing that case first.

Comment: You mean instead of n=n, set it to 2 to see the pattern?

Comment: Yes. $\textbf{}$

Comment: I checked the distribution and it is correct.

Comment: It's not, I assure you.

Comment: oh...wait...the subtraction part basically the second half looks a bit off. I will go edit that.

Comment: Yes, and if you fix that, you will get the right answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12039/discussion-between-user983246-and-potato)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. $|u|^2=u\cdot u$, so $$\|u+v\|^2 -\|u-v\|^2 = (u+v)(u+v)-(u-v)(u-v)=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without using the seperate coordinates, by using $||x||=\sqrt{x\cdot x}$.
Can you that yourself?